# Stackexchange android app does not highlight questions with favourite tags unlike site

Tags: feature-request, tags, android-app, tag-watching

It would be nice if we get this feature on android app where questions with preferred tags are highlighted just like how it is on website.

**Website view:**

[image: Website view]

===========================

**Android app view:**

[image: Android app view]

Comment: Missed it. I am sad to see that it's not fixed from last two years

Comment: With only a single developer working on the android app, there are things with much higher priority. Not saying it's a lost cause, but "nice to have" feature requests like this might take long years to reach the top of the "To Do" list.

Comment: This I believe is one of the essential features. Can save lot of time of readers to read questions they want rather than having to go through them all. Worth pushing I guess